# set Heroku CORS headers

Tags: heroku, cors

I have a question with a probable obvious answer that I need to understand. I have come to the point where I need to "Add CORS headers to the server". I haven't been able to find a comprehensive guide of how to do this in Heroku. Or is is something that doesn't have to do with Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something that you set at the Heroku level. You'd need to set CORS headers in the language/framework in which your application is written. This would be whatever is in the `web:` section of your `Procfile`.

If you give more details about your application, and tag the question with the framework/language, you'll probably get a more precise answer (whether from me or somebody else).